# parse strange JSON response as List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, restsharp

I am calling a webservice using RestSharp and getting my response back properly but the data I get back is in kind of a weird format.  It is a list of GUIDS which is also what I want but they come back as a bool object or something, have a look:

```
"{
    \"5916DF70-C413-4132-90F7-C365B0FAA26D\" : true,
    \"B5F0FF80-F8D1-40F7-8313-045F02D37FAA\" : true,
    \"D859A904-EDAE-4D87-9ADC-8FB5F3B47B02\" : true
}"
```

How would I parse that so I just get a List that contains just the GUIDs?

Comment: That is standard JSON with quotes escaped.  What do you mean it's a "weird format"?

Comment: I am not worried about the escaping but normally you would expect  { name : value } which I could easily serialize to a class, here the property name is actually the value I need to extract as a list - make sense?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cant really parse that response to a list it looks more like a dictionary

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<Guid, bool>>(json);
var resultlist = result.Select(c => c.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: doh, so used to always looking for a complete object to deserialize to a class I missed the obvious, thanks